# Show/hide table rows based on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a toggle button next to a table to hide or show table rows based on the whether or not a checkbox in the last column of the table is checked.

Here is the code for the table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1<td>
    <td>Text<td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" checked="checked"><td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2<td>
    <td>Text<td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the sidebar I have this button:

```html
<a id="comtoggle" class="btn" href="#">Toggle</a>
```

In the above example, I would like for row 1 to disappear if the Toggle button is clicked, but have it reappear if the toggle button is clicked again. The state of the checkbox is stored in a database and is saved via an AJAX function (which works fine).

Here is the jQuery I have. I think my problem is using the **.is(':checked')** in the 3rd line.

```jquery
$("#comtoggle").click(function() {
  if ($('.form-checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $('.form-checkbox').is(':checked').closest('tr').toggle();
  }
});
```

With this snippet, all of my rows disappear, and the console of Firebug shows this error:

`TypeError: $target.offset(...) is null`

Not sure if it is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is what you mean. Catch the fiddle aswell: http://jsfiddle.net/7C423/1
All you need to do is just grab that what you are interested in and play the ball.

```
$("#comtoggle").click(function() {
      $(".form-checkbox:checked").closest("tr").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Guess I was over thinking it with the if statement. Now to hide the column... Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are selecting elements by class, you need to loop trough them and in case they are checked hide a row.

`$("#comtoggle").click(function() {
    $('.form-checkbox').each(function(chk){
       if($(this).is(':checked'))
          $(this).closest("tr").toggle();
    });
});`